# how to check if end of List Items is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

hey guys i am working on a slider and on up and down arrow keys i am shifting the slides.
Now i am unable to do this but how can I check if ok LI's has reached so i can something like scrolling back to top.
thanks.
here is my code for prev and next

```
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {

        var next = ul.find('li.current').next();

        if (next.length) {
            next.click();
            ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current');
            next.addClass('current');
        }
    }
});
$("#thumbsList li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('currentThumbNail');

    $('#thumbsList li').not(this).removeClass('currentThumbNail');

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `else` branch after your `if (next.length) {` seems good enough to me.

```
    if (next.length) {
        next.click();
        ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current');
        next.addClass('current');
    }
    else {
        //no more slides found, dammit!
    }
```

Comment: and for loop you can use `ui.find('li').eq(0).addClass('current')` in `else{}`